# Quorum problem to find external node

Tags: quorum

I have tried several configurations without success. I am trying to connect two nodes there are in different network. Both are in a VM at google cloud, as you can see in the image below, one of them is not active. I have already opened all the ports to let it work and still not working. If I create both locally, they work, but when they are not locally, I have no success. What am I missing? I am using quorum in a private network

[image]

Comment: This is likely a connectivity issue -- if both nodes are up, you need to check if the network  permissions are set so they can connect to each other.

Comment: I was thought that was the problem, but I receive that the connection is open with telnet for the ports 50000 and 21000, that ports are the one I am using in my node. I am using this command to start my node.

PRIVATE_CONFIG=ignore geth --datadir new-node-1 --nodiscover --verbosity 5 --networkid 31337 --raft --raftport 50000 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 22000 --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,quorum,raft --emitcheckpoints --port 21000

Comment: What does the log have? Are there any errors logged?

Comment: these are the logs that I am getting in one node.
TRACE[06-11|15:02:34.702] Accepted connection                      addr=34.82.58.110:41168
TRACE[06-11|15:02:34.704] Failed RLPx handshake                    addr=34.82.58.110:41168 conn=inbound    err="ecies: invalid message"
TRACE[06-11|15:02:34.704] Setting up connection failed             addr=34.82.58.110:41168 err="ecies: invalid message"

Both have the same genesis file this is my static-nodes.json file
[
"enode://enode1@127.0.0.1:21000?discport=0&raftport=50000",  "enode://enode2@34.82.58.110:21000?discport=0&raftport=50000"
]

Comment: This isn't a very familiar issue but light googling suggest something might be up in networking config. Can you share more info? What do you have in the static-nodes file? Also, this 1 day turn around time on here is a bit laggy, so if you like live support for your issue you should join our slack here: https://www.goquorum.com/slack-inviter